# What is wrong with this? (I searched for the error for hours)

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Location1 As String
    Dim city As Boolean
    Dim sss As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid ip address")
    Else
        city = True
        sss = False
        geoip()
        If Label1.Text = "" Or Label1.Text = " " Then
            city = False
        Else
            city = True
            Location1 = Label1.Text
        End If
        If city = False And Label16.Text = "" Or Label16.Text = " " Then
            Location1 = Label17.Text
        Else
            sss = True
        End If
        If sss = True Then
            Location1 = Label16.Text
        End If
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TextBox2.Text = "We look forward to meet you tomorrow at the meeting place at 1 PM, the package has been shipped already to you to " + Location1 + ". If you wont be there for completing the transaction, we will need to proceed to stage 2."
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        TextBox2.Text = "My name is " + TextBox3.Text + " from " + TextBox4.Text + " and im here for letting you know that we look forward to meet you tomorrow at the meeting place at 1 PM, the package has been shipped already to you to " + Location1 + ". If you wont be there for completing the transaction, we will need to proceed to stage 2."
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

And it doesn't work as intended. It displays even when label1 is not `""` or `" "` as label 16, I searched for the error in the code for so much time, but I think all is good

Comment: *And it doesnt work as meant* You think someone's gonna guess what you mean?

Comment: Please try and explain your logic in words....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand your question - I'm leaving my old answer since it is correct to bracket conditions and your code would still have broken, but your problem was that you have your `If ... else`s such that you fall into the `else` in places you wouldn't want to.

For example - Consider this line in your code:

```
If city = False And Label16.Text = "" Or Label16.Text = " " Then
    Location1 = Label17.Text
Else
    sss = True
End If
```

That `else` will be hit if city is true or if there's something in in label 16. You'd only want it to get there **if city is still false** and there's something in label 16....

Rather focus on doing your logic by nesting your conditional logic. This code should work as expected:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Location1 As String
    Dim city As Boolean
    Dim sss As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid ip address")
    Else
        geoip()

        If Label1.Text.Trim() = "" Then
            city = False

            If Label16.Text.Trim() = "" Then
                Location1 = Label17.Text
            Else
                sss = True
                Location1 = Label16.Text
            End If
        Else
            city = True
            Location1 = Label1.Text
        End If
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TextBox2.Text = "We look forward to meet you tomorrow at the meeting place at 1 PM, the package has been shipped already to you to " + Location1 + ". If you wont be there for completing the transaction, we will need to proceed to stage 2."
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        TextBox2.Text = "My name is " + TextBox3.Text + " from " + TextBox4.Text + " and im here for letting you know that we look forward to meet you tomorrow at the meeting place at 1 PM, the package has been shipped already to you to " + Location1 + ". If you wont be there for completing the transaction, we will need to proceed to stage 2."
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, @ЯшаКарагзов, Id' suggest getting into the habit of naming my controls - Rather than having a control named `Label1`, give it a meaningful name like `lblCity` or something... That will let you know exactly what you're dealing with and make your code infinitely more readable!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding your question as stated, but am pretty sure your issue has to do with bracketing your clauses.

Your line `If city = False And Label16.Text = "" Or Label16.Text = " " Then` reads right to you, but isn't being understood correctly by the compiler... Always bracket complex logic statements to be safe.

Try and change this:

```
If city = False And Label16.Text = "" Or Label16.Text = " " Then
```

to this:

```
If city = False And (Label16.Text = "" Or Label16.Text = " ") Then
```

Or, please explain the problem a bit better...

Comment: ...or a simple trim: `Label16.Text.Trim = ""` to get rid of the OR.

Comment: 100% agreed, @LarsTech. I'll leave my answer as-is just to point out the need for brackets for times it can't be fixed that way, but your answer is actually the way I'd want it programmed too!

Comment: Didnt work :/ I dont know what is wrong, but it just does something strange, the logic seem normal, but the program puts label16 instead of label1

Comment: What do you mean by "it puts label16 instead of label1" - That doesn't make any sense to me....

Comment: I mean that it sets "Location1" to the text of "label16" instead of to the text of "label1"

Comment: @ЯшаКарагзов Learn to use the debugger to step through your code line by line and inspect the values so you can see why things happen the way they do.

Comment: @ЯшаКарагзов, I just posted a different answer that should solve your issue, but please consider both answers for future programming...

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the `IsNumeric` function won't work for a ip address. Try to split the ip and then check with `IsNumeric`.

Comment: Pretty sure the user is complaining about the "else" part of the condition.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read the whole question.

Comment: Yes, im complaining about the else part